# How can I write my PHP code to use pointers and references with SWIG?

Tags: php, c++, swig

I am using SWIG to wrap my C++ source code, but my code has pointers and references. How can I write my PHP code to use these functions? My C++ class is as follows:

```
Bitmap : public Image
{
public:
    void fillColor(const unsigned int *color);
};
```

How can I call `fillColor()` in my PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for : http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html#Php_nn2_5

You have 3 options - I'd think the most natural would be to simply include "phppointers.i" to your .swg or .i swig files and call your vars REF.
Then you can just use them in PHP as you would in C++, but they are called references instead of pointers (just write an ampsersand & before the $ of your variable).

Comment: I had try it, but it doesn't work! it says "PHP Fatal error:  Type error in argument 2 of Bitmap_fillColor. Expected SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_int in /home/phpmodule.php on line 812"

Comment: Can we have a little more detail of your code ? The files that you feed to swig and you PHP code for instance ?

Comment: @xiangyun - you'll need to tell SWIG what the `unsigned int*` actually is - is it an array? (how big?) Is it an IN/OUT single integer? or just IN / just OUT?